# Could we include arcgis on our current tag policy?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags

Now that we have the [tags related to arcgis](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3131/using-tags-on-arcgis-questions) well organized (thanks to PolyGeo) I wonder if we could improve this policy tying up some loose ends.

One argument in favor of using detailed tags was that people would be able to easily find questions within a specific subject, and it would lead to more answers on questions. So far, everything ok.

However, some counter arguments still remained from the last talk. They were:

- rettagments of old threads would be a problem.
- people interested in the topic arcgis in a general manner would have difficulties to subscribe to questions with so segmented arcgis tags.

But what if we keep adding the specific tags, but also maintaining [arcgis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcgis)?
I mean, let it be in a broader sense (differently from what we current have on its tag excerpt).

I only see advantages on doing this.

- less retagging needed (no need to remove arcgis, when all the other tags are ok).
- people would be able to subscribe to arcgis, and search for arcgis in a general manner.
- we could keep one of our main tags and continue to advance with past [work](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tags/arcgis/topusers).

I see no harm aggregating this policy on the current one. Most posts do not use all 5 available tag rooms.
So, if a user label a question with: arcgis, arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1; and the post really is about arcgis-desktop version 10.1, just let all the 3 tags be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess I should be somewhat sympathetic to this argument since I apparently have the top answer score on the [arcgis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcgis) tag, but honestly that doesn't mean much to me.

**ArcGIS is a brand, not a product.** You can't call up Esri and ask to buy ArcGIS, at least not without a few billion dollars in the bank. They will ask what problem you are trying to solve and try to sell you a product or three.

In almost every instance I've seen, using the [arcgis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcgis) tag is just a result of ignorance of the existence of the product tags, or even knowledge of what product one is using.

I think the community has done well to organize the tags as they are. You should see our [ELA](http://www.esri.com/industries/ela), it's vast. The sheer number of products under the brand is almost mind-boggling.

Regarding tag subscriptions, I find it unlikely that many people are truly interested in being subscribed to every single ArcGIS-related question. How hard it is it to just subscribe to the products you are *actually* interested in? That said, [apparently it *is* possible](http://stackexchange.com/filters):

[image: ArcGIS Filter]

As for the [arcgis-platform](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcgis-platform) tag, I could take it or leave it. It's basically the same as the [arcgis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcgis) tag. Esri is trying to package its current products under a "new" brand in order to increase sales, but it's basically the same thing. I would like to hear a convincing argument to the contrary, though.

**TL, DR:**

- If people have questions about ArcGIS, the brand, then they should use the [arcgis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcgis) tag.
- If they have questions about an ArcGIS-branded product, they should use one of the product-specific tags.
- If you really want to subscribe to every ArcGIS-related question, [you can](http://stackexchange.com/filters).

Comment: Tks for you and PolyGeo's answer. Let's wait a few days to see if there will be further point of views.

Comment: I'm not wedded to the [tag:arcgis-platform] tag but use it to distinguish those questions involving multiple ArcGIS products from those tagged [tag:arcgis] which probably involve only one - but which one?  *De facto* blacklisting of [tag:arcgis] along with the remainder of your Answer appears to be the practical solution to disambiguation.  If ArcGIS re-brands to something other than a platform then a simple synonym can address that quickly then.

Comment: It's been a while and nobody else stepped in so I'm willing to join @PolyGeo's and yours opinion. You addressed well the loose point #2 (subscribing to arcgis, i.e, it is possible), and PolyGeo provided an alternative to the loose point #1 (retaggements of old threads) which is to blacklist arcgis (another alternative to avoid retagging would be to leave old threads the way they are, unless there are other improvements to do along with the edit).

Answer (score 2):

The [arcgis-platform](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcgis-platform) tag is there for "people interested in the topic arcgis in a general manner".

As ArcGIS Pro and ArcGIS Online questions increase it becomes clear that [arcgis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcgis) commonly means different things to different people e.g. [arcgis-pro](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcgis-pro), [arcgis-online](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcgis-online), [arcgis-desktop](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcgis-desktop), [arcgis-server](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcgis-server) i.e. it has the hallmarks of a [meta-tag](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/), and I think a meta-tag is a wasted tag.

The first thing I look for when working out whether I can answer a question from the ArcGIS platform is the ArcGIS product being used i.e. can I even test it?

That's why, at least for ArcGIS platform questions, I think being able to filter by product tags is near-critical.