# What's the process to add a new tag if you're under 300 rep

Tags: discussion, tags

What's the process to add a **new tag** if you're **under 300 rep**. For example I want to add "arcgis-10.3.1" but I'm only 186 rep. Do we open a chat with a moderator, or add a comment on the post, or is there another method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the preferred way to coin a new tag before getting to the reputation needed to do that would be to add a comment on the post.  Flagging a moderator to add it is also possible but I think coining a tag would be borderline when flagging is meant to be the course of last resort.

In this case I, for one, would be very likely to make a tag of [arcgis-10.3.1](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcgis-10.3.1) (if one appeared) become a synonym of [arcgis-10.3](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcgis-10.3) because we gained reasonable consensus a long time ago in [Tagging ArcGIS questions?](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3131/using-tags-on-arcgis-questions) that we would not go more fine grained than dot releases of ArcGIS products.