# Disambiguating some ArcPy questions whose answers depend on whether ArcGIS Pro is being used?

Tags: discussion

There is a question on Main ([Add/Remove Relate using ArcPy without ArcGIS Pro?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/172851/add-remove-relate-in-arcgis-pro-but-not-arcpy)) whose content may later be edited but it currently includes:

> I am trying to add a relate between 2 feature classes so that I can
>   use the area of the related table to update a field in the original
>   table. I found an ArcGIS Pro article
>   (http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/add-relate.htm)
>   for doing this, but a similar feature does not seem to exist in ArcPy.

I think this is typical of a class of question which I expect to see frequently while ArcPy developers are transitioning from the ArcGIS 10.x architecture applications (ArcMap, ArcCatalog, ArcScene, ArcGlobe) to ArcGIS Pro.

As a result I asked, also on Main, [Terminology for distinguishing ArcPy installed with ArcGIS 10.x for Desktop from that which comes with ArcGIS Pro?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/172856/how-should-arcpy-be-referred-to-when-used-with-arcgis-pro)  I asked it there rather than here because I thought that there may have been a terminology used in ArcGIS presentations/documentation somewhere like perhaps "ArcPy Pro" (Python 3, ArcGIS Pro) vs ArcPy (Python 2, ArcMap, etc).  That was therefore not a question about the software that drives GIS SE and instead was about a GIS platform.

The reason that I did this is that a question as simple sounding as:

> Does ArcPy have an AddRelate_management tool?

is no longer unambiguous.

Since the release of ArcGIS Pro with ArcGIS 10.3.x for Desktop there are two valid answers:

- [Yes](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/add-relate.htm), if you are using Python 3.x and able to call functions from ArcGIS Pro
- [No](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/an-overview-of-the-joins-toolset.htm), if you are using Python 2.x and only able to call functions from the ArcGIS 10.x applications

This is just one of several questions on Main that I have seen so far that illustrate the need to qualify *some* ArcPy questions by also stating whether they are using it with ArcGIS Pro or one of the  ArcGIS 10.x architecture applications and/or from Python 2.x or 3.x.  Some other examples are:

- [Forcing Python Toolbox tool to break loop and do cleanup when user clicks Cancel?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/172598/forcing-python-toolbox-tool-to-break-loop-and-do-cleanup-when-user-clicks-cancel)
- https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/167732/running-custom-geoprocessing-tools-written-for-arcgis-10-x-for-desktop-in-arcgis
- [Migrating ArcGIS for Desktop script to ArcGIS Pro?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/172940/migrating-arcgis-for-desktop-script-to-arcgis-pro)

Many of our ArcPy users are not going to be familiar with the differences in tools and modules available when using ArcPy in the two contexts, and since I am one of the people who will be looking at their questions, I can see myself asking frequently for them to be more precise about the context in which they are using ArcPy.

Should we recommend to our users that when ArcPy is key to their questions, it will help us if they can also let us know whether they are using it with ArcGIS Pro and Python 3, or not?

If this seems like a wise thing to do then that advice could be added to [Tagging ArcGIS questions?](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3131/using-tags-on-arcgis-questions)