# What to do with ArcGIS tag after burnination?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate

The ambiguous [arcgis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcgis) tag is approaching [burnination](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate) with less than 50 questions still bearing it, and still needing their content checked to determine whether they should be re-tagged as [arcgis-desktop](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcgis-desktop), [arcgis-server](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcgis-server), [arcgis-online](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcgis-online), or another `arc*` tag.

The background to why [arcgis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcgis) ceased to be considered a useful tag is covered in [Tagging ArcGIS questions?](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3131/using-tags-on-arcgis-questions)

What should happen to the [arcgis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcgis) tag when its count reaches 0?

Some options are:

- Do nothing - inevitably this will see someone with enough [privilege to create a tag](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags) resurrect it, probably on an almost daily basis.
- [Blacklist](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19018/implement-a-tag-black-list) it - which will mean that it cannot be used, just like the `gis`, `spatial` and `geospatial` tags cannot - users trying to type it will need to choose something else.
- Make it a synonym of [arcgis-platform](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcgis-platform) - this term does not seem to be in general use but as a "catch all" it would be accurate.
- Make it a synonym of [arcgis-desktop](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcgis-desktop) - this is still what most users mean when they say ArcGIS.
- Make it a synonym of [arcgis-online](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcgis-online) - this is what a significant subset of users now start to call ArcGIS.
- Make it a synonym of something else.
- Something else?

Comment: Presumably if you blacklist it, users trying to type arcgis will see all the other alternatives in the suggestion box and be able to make their own choice?

Comment: @SideshowBob That's right - try typing spatial as a tag to see the equivalent experience

Comment: Can the same be done for the arcmap tag, since the arcgis-desktop tag "should normally be used in preference"?

Comment: @Barbarossa I don't think there is a case for [tag:arcmap] being burninated.  Those using it without [tag:arcgis-desktop] simply risk not reaching the filters of some potential answerers.  If I see [tag:arcmap] unaccompanied by [tag:arcgis-desktop] I add the latter, but I would not normally remove an [tag:arcmap] tag unless it is occupying a slot needed for [tag:arcgis-desktop].

Comment: The [tag:ArcGIS] tag has now been blacklisted.  Thanks for your support to enable this to happen.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

<sub>Firstly, congratulations! It was quite a job organizing the 'arcgis' tag.</sub>

I believe we should definitely blacklist it.

- Users will use the correct tag from now on (when typing 'arcgis', they will see the alternative tags and be able to make the correct choice, as mentioned by Sideshow Bob).
- There will be less tag-editings bumping posts to the active page, which is good because minor edits take away attention of posts with new answers and from posts substantially edited.

Doing nothing will make the problem to come back. In the best scenario, making it a synonym of 'arcgis-desktop' would only reduce the amount of posts incorrectly tagged. [Idem](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/idem) for making it a synonym of something else.

Comment: Agreed on all parts. Nice work @PolyGeo--it has been an epic job on your part cleaning the arcgis suite of tags.

Comment: I agree with this completely as well. Blacklisting the tag seems like the most logical choice at this point.

Comment: Blacklisting of the former [tag:arcgis] tag was just completed - thanks for your support on this.  It was a hard sell to the community in the early days but I believe it had to be done, and knowing you, @Aaron and others were onboard made the mop up much easier.