# Are version tags needed for ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: discussion, tags, version-tags

[Tagging ArcGIS questions?](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3131/using-tags-on-arcgis-questions) recommends using the [arcgis-pro](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcgis-pro) tag for ArcGIS Pro questions but makes no recommendations for dealing with the tagging of ArcGIS Pro versions.

Today, an [arcgis-pro-1.3](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcgis-pro-1.3) tag became the first ArcGIS Pro version tag to be used.

Do we need version tags for ArcGIS Pro and, if so, to what granularity?

Comment: I just set this to [meta-tag:status-completed] after making [tag:arcgis-pro-1.3] a synonym of [tag:arcgis-pro].  The case for doing this was far from overwhelming and so I did not take the next step of merging the two tags.

Comment: I've removed [tag:status-completed] on this to enable my ArcGIS Pro 2.0 answer to get some consideration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As each dot release of ArcGIS Pro has occurred I have wondered whether or not version tags for it might be desirable.

I have been a proponent of version tags for dot releases of the ArcGIS platform (ArcGIS for Desktop, ArcGIS for Server, ArcGIS Engine, etc) but have so far refrained from creating them for ArcGIS Pro.  I think there is a difference between how version tags of the two architectures might help/hinder questions to attract potential answerers here.

In the case of the ArcGIS platform prior to ArcGIS Pro I think the recommendation to always apply a product and a version tag is sound.  It was and remains particularly useful when assessing options for how to answer questions at the 9.3 to 10.0 major change, and also at the 10.0 to 10.1 change which was big for ArcPy (arcpy.da, Python Toolboxes, Python AddIns).  Even today many years after the release of 10.0 we still see quite a few questions using that version.

In contrast, I think the changeover in ArcGIS Pro dot releases, while just as big, and probably much bigger, than in ArcGIS 10.x for Desktop, will not see versions lingering on to anything like the same degree.  I think the ease and desirability of upgrading during ArcGIS Pro 1.x means that we can almost assume a question will be using the latest version within a month or two of that release.  Perhaps as ArcGIS Pro becomes more important to larger enterprises we will start to see more inertia and risk around upgrading but for now I think when someone asks an ArcGIS Pro question we can safely assume that an answer using or mindful of ArcGIS Pro 1.3 is what they will be looking for.

For now I think we should continue to use a single [arcgis-pro](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcgis-pro) tag for ArcGIS Pro and reassess whether it may need version (and perhaps dot release) tags when it eventually gets to a 2.x version.

Comment: +1 - You make good points, however I think you also need to consider the ArcGIS Pro version when it comes to *searching* for answers.  If I were to search for a solution to a problem and find a solution that was relevant to 1.1 but I'm using 1.3 (the current release), the accepted answer to that 1.1 question may actually not be relevant, or even be incorrect, for 1.3.  This is why I used a 1.3 tag in my question, as the solution is very different to 1.0-1.2

Comment: @Midavalo I'm thinking that most people working with ArcGIS Pro will be mindful of that rate of change and looking closely at the body of the question and answers for version numbers.  I think that is less likely to catch someone out than looking only at the [tag:arcgis-pro] tag and not doing an exploded `[arcgis-pro-*]` search using the search bar to pick up those that are version tagged.  I think there may be merit to version tags for ArcGIS Pro in time, but at this relatively early stage of a new architecture I think it may be applying over-granularity.

Comment: As always, whenever we see outdated answers, I think we should seek to clarify the version(s) they apply to and add new answers more relevant to the current version, if needed.

Answer (score 0):

In asking my question [How to set up Python/ArcPy with ArcGIS Pro 1.3](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/203380/how-to-set-up-python-arcpy-with-arcgis-pro-1-3) I noted that there is only a single [arcgis-pro](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcgis-pro) tag, nothing specific to each version.

For my question I created a new [arcgis-pro-1.3](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcgis-pro-1.3) tag as the question isn't relevant pre-1.3, and I wonder whether it is worth having different tags for each different ArcGIS Pro release due to the number of differences in functionality between the different releases?  Each release includes a lot of new features, so a question for 1.1 may not be at all relevant to 1.0 etc.

I think there should be new tags for ArcGIS Pro:

- [arcgis-pro-1.0](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcgis-pro-1.0)
- [arcgis-pro-1.1](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcgis-pro-1.1)
- [arcgis-pro-1.2](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcgis-pro-1.2)
- [arcgis-pro-1.3](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcgis-pro-1.3) (added by me today)