# Reviewing ArcGIS Pro tagging post-release of version 2.0?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

Now that ArcGIS Pro 2.0 has been released, and new questions in that version are outnumbering those about the earlier versions, I think we should revisit [Changes to ArcGIS Pro tag in preparation for ArcGIS Pro 2](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4515/changes-to-arcgis-pro-tag-in-preparation-for-arcgis-pro-2)

In [my answer](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4516/115) to that I said:

> I am assuming that ArcGIS Pro 2.0 will be sufficiently enhanced from
>   ArcGIS Pro 1.4 to warrant its major release number and our
>   distinction.

We currently have tags for [arcgis-pro-1](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcgis-pro-1) and [arcgis-pro-2](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcgis-pro-2), while [arcgis-pro](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcgis-pro) redirects to [arcgis-pro-1](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcgis-pro-1) (may be switched to [arcgis-pro-2](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcgis-pro-2) soon).

Does my assumption above seem to be holding, or should we merge tags [arcgis-pro-1](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcgis-pro-1) and [arcgis-pro-2](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcgis-pro-2) into a single [arcgis-pro](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcgis-pro) tag?

Comment: So far, I think we have four options: i) [your answer](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4515/changes-to-arcgis-pro-tag-in-preparation-for-arcgis-pro-2/4516#4516); ii) [my answer](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4515/changes-to-arcgis-pro-tag-in-preparation-for-arcgis-pro-2/4523#4523); iii) your answer, but blacklisting [tag:arcgis-pro] (complement suggested at the end of my answer); and iv) the new proposal (written in this question) merging [tag:arcgis-pro-1] and [tag:arcgis-pro-2]. I think ii), iii) and iv) are valid solutions, but i) is terrible.

Comment: @AndreSilva I think "terrible" is far too harsh but agree that the option you labelled i) is sub-optimal in hindsight.

Comment: I think we have enough votes to implement the merge of two tags into [tag:arcgis-pro] and so that has been done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the original Q&A transpired I was expecting the differences between ArcGIS Pro versions 1.x and 2.0 to be far greater.  They are certainly significant, and I do encourage users to upgrade to 2.0 sooner rather than later to take advantage of them.  However, I think the case for maintaining two version tags within ArcGIS Pro is much weaker than expected.

Consequently, I think that we should:

1. Rename [arcgis-pro-1](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcgis-pro-1) back to [arcgis-pro](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcgis-pro), which is easily done via `swap` in the moderator tool for managing Tag Synonyms
2. Merge [arcgis-pro-2](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcgis-pro-2) into [arcgis-pro](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcgis-pro), which is easily done by a  moderator

I know that this is the opposite of what I proposed and implemented in the earlier Q&A but now we have the benefit of seeing another major release of ArcGIS Pro for the first time, and are thus in a much better position to judge the benefits of those two alternatives.

I think more benefit will accrue to our ArcGIS Pro users if all non-SDK ArcGIS Pro Q&As (at least those tagged correctly) have this one tag.

This more or less mirrors the situation for the older ArcGIS Desktop 10.x architecture where all non-developer ArcGIS Desktop Q&As (at least those tagged correctly) have one key tag of [arcgis-desktop](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcgis-desktop).

With only 264 non-SDK ArcGIS Pro questions asked so far I think it is better to make the switch now rather than later.

Comment: Agreed - We may need to reassess this in the future if we find there is a huge change, but currently the differences as well as the user upgrade lag aren't as major as I was expecting.

Comment: I think we have enough votes to implement the merge of two tags into [tag:arcgis-pro] and so that has been done.