# Synonymizing ArcGIS dot release tags with ArcGIS major release tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, version-tags

The GIS Meta Q&A on [Keep or delete [qgis-3] version tag?](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4925/keep-or-delete-qgis-3-version-tag) has resulted in:

- all the QGIS 3.x tags being made synonyms of the [qgis-3](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qgis-3) tag; and
- all the QGIS 2.x tags being made synonyms of the [qgis-2](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qgis-2) tag
- the two QGIS 1.x tags being made synonyms of the [qgis-1](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qgis-1) tag

Should we now do the same for the version tags being used with ArcGIS Desktop and ArcGIS Server?

Answer (score 4):

I do not agree. There are significant changes to ArcGIS in v10 later versions, including but not limited to:

- Support for ASPRS LAS v1.4.
- Support for GDA2020.
- Classify LAS building and Tile LAS tools.

Read more about [What's new in 10.5](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.5/get-started/introduction/whats-new-in-arcgis.htm). The sub-releases only contain minor changes and bugfixes but each minor release contains significant changes. If a user is limited *only* to ArcGIS 10 as a tag there is a potential for confusion if they are using an earlier release and are receiving answers in a later release, this would mean for *every* question tagged ArcGIS 10 the first comment would always be "*which minor version of ArcGIS 10 do you have installed?*".

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

I think we should make:

- all the ArcGIS 10.x tags become synonyms of an [arcgis-10](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcgis-10) tag; and
- all the ArcGIS 9.x tags become synonyms of an [arcgis-9](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcgis-9) tag

The reasons that I think we should do this are:

- to simplify ArcGIS version tagging
- the case for separate dot release tags was strong in the ArcGIS 9.1, 9.2, 9.3, 10.0 and 10.1 era but with each subsequent dot release changes between them have become more and more minor

I strongly encourage askers of ArcGIS questions to always mention the precise version(s) they are asking about within the body of those questions.  If they do that, then I think the case for using any version tags on ArcGIS questions becomes weak, and I think it may be useful to stop using version tags.  The above could be another intermediate step towards that, and in line with what we already do for ArcGIS Pro (see [Are version tags needed for ArcGIS Pro?](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4280/are-version-tags-needed-for-arcgis-pro)).

Comment: 10.0 and 10.1 were similar releases, however I believe 10.2 or 10.3 was a fairly major update, and there is significant difference between 10.1 and 10.3.  I'm not sure quite how we could accommodate that though, or if we even should.  But overall I agree that we should try to synonymize where we can

Comment: @Midavalo If you're talking "Server": Server underwent _massive_ changes between <=10.0 and >=10.1. Desktop has had a relatively even increase in enhancements over each .dot release (noting the biggest changes were 9.3 to 10.0, a full release)

Comment: @Midavalo the big differences I saw between 10.0 and 10.1 was in ArcPy when arcpy.da, Python Toolboxes and Python AddIns were added.

Comment: If there's no way to distinguish between 10.1 and 10.6 via tags, then the arcgis-10 tag will be worthless. Posters keep tagging 10.5 questions as 10.0, so I'd be fine with retiring 10.0/10.1 from service, but you might as well synonymize arcgis-10 with arcgis for all the use it would be.

Comment: @Vince I kind of agree.  I thought about proposing [tag:arcgis-10.0], [tag:arcgis-10.1] and [tag:arcgis-10.2+].  I've gone for the simplest version tagging possible.  I'm aware that it only distinguishes between ArcGIS 9.x (few questions) and 10.x.