# Adding ArcGIS-10.7 tag

Tags: discussion, tags, version-tags

It looks like the ArcGIS 10.7 tag has not yet been added to GIS SE.

Now that 10.7 is available, should we add this tag?

Comment: Related: https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5028/synonymizing-arcgis-dot-release-tags-with-arcgis-major-release-tags

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have now created the [arcgis-10.7](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcgis-10.7) tag.