# Tagging ArcGIS Enterprise, Server, Portal, ArcSDE, etc questions?

Tags: discussion, tags

With [ArcGIS 10.5 now in Prerelease](https://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2016/10/13/arcgis-10-5-prerelease-is-now-available/) it seems timely to re-examine how the server products from that platform are tagged because:

> If you haven’t already heard the product family formerly known as
>   ArcGIS for Server has been renamed to ArcGIS Enterprise.

From [What is ArcGIS Enterprise?](https://server.arcgis.com/en/server/10.5/get-started/windows/what-is-arcgis-enterprise-.htm) it has four components:

- ArcGIS Server
- Portal for ArcGIS
- ArcGIS Data Store
- ArcGIS Web Adaptor

How should we tag server products and components from the ArcGIS platform going forward?

I think any tagging scheme proposed should include consideration of what to do with the [arcsde](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcsde) tag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They should continue to be tagged the way they are now. [arcgis-server](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcgis-server) [web-adaptor](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web-adaptor) [arcgis-portal](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcgis-portal). I **do not** see the need for some enterprise tag. It would be the same as adding the 'arcgis' tag to anything Esri related. ArcGIS Enterprise is a collection of software:

> A base ArcGIS Enterprise deployment consists of a combination of three
>   primary components—Portal for ArcGIS, ArcGIS Server, and ArcGIS Data
>   Store—that together comprise a Web GIS. This provides foundational
>   mapping and analysis capabilities along with secure sharing, app
>   infrastructure, and information management functionality. ArcGIS
>   Server must be licensed at the GIS Server Standard or GIS Server
>   Advanced level in this deployment. See Base ArcGIS Enterprise
>   deployment for details.

Someone who comes to the site asking "I need help with setting up ArcGIS Enterprise" will be asked to narrow down their question. They'll have a specific problem with one of the components, not the entire process. If they do, thats a call to tech support or again, be called upon to be specific in their problem.