# Re-tagging to de-emphasize ArcGIS Desktop product in favour of its applications?

Tags: discussion, tags

At [Using tags [arcmap] and [arcgis-desktop]?](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4893) consensus is being built to cease tagging every new question about the ArcGIS Desktop product with the [arcgis-desktop](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcgis-desktop) tag in favour of a tagging scheme that will be, or very similar to:

- [arcmap](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcmap) for questions about **ArcMap**
- [arccatalog](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arccatalog) for questions about **ArcCatalog**
- [arcglobe](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcglobe) for questions about **ArcGlobe**
- [arcscene](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcscene) for questions about **ArcScene**
- [arcgis-pro](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcgis-pro) for questions about **ArcGIS Pro**
- [arcmap](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcmap) and [3d-analyst](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/3d-analyst) for questions about ArcMap that use toolbars and geoprocessing tools that are only available with **3D Analyst** licensing
- [arcgis-pro](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcgis-pro) and [3d-analyst](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/3d-analyst) for questions about ArcGIS Pro that use ribbon tools and geoprocessing tools that are only available with **3D Analyst** licensing
- [arcmap](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcmap) and [spatial-analyst](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spatial-analyst) for questions about ArcMap that use toolbars and geoprocessing tools that are only available with **Spatial Analyst** licensing
- [arcgis-pro](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcgis-pro) and [spatial-analyst](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spatial-analyst) for questions about ArcGIS Pro that use ribbon tools and geoprocessing tools that are only available with **Spatial Analyst** licensing
- [arcmap](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcmap) and [network-analyst](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/network-analyst) for questions about ArcMap that use toolbars and geoprocessing tools that are only available with **Network Analyst** licensing
- [arcgis-pro](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcgis-pro) and [network-analyst](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/network-analyst) for questions about ArcGIS Pro that use ribbon tools and geoprocessing tools that are only available with **Network Analyst** licensing
- <s>[arcmap](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcmap) and [arcpy](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcpy) for questions about **ArcPy** with the ArcGIS Desktop 10.x architecture</s>
- <s>[arcgis-pro](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcgis-pro) and [arcpy](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcpy) for questions about **ArcPy** with ArcGIS Pro</s>
- [arcobjects](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcobjects) for questions about **ArcObjects**

Assuming that this consensus is reached, how can we implement it using largely automated steps so as to avoid a massive manual re-tagging exercise?

Comment: [tag:arcpy] with [tag:arcmap] I believe is incorrect.  I believe this should refer to the version number, not the desktop application.  eg [tag:arcpy] [tag:arcgis-10.5]

Comment: @Midavalo I'd hoped to keep ArcGIS version tags out of the discussion.  To me they are a separate part of the unease I've felt with the current ArcGIS tagging, and I'd like to leave discussion of them for a second phase.  The main gist of the ArcPy/ArcMap tagging pair is to distinguish it from ArcPy/ArcGIS Pro.  Maybe we just acknowledge that since the geoprocessing framework spans all five ArcGIS Desktop applications, tagging pairs like ArcPy/ArcCatalog, ArcPy/ArcGlobe and ArcPy/ArcScene are also likely to be used in small numbers.

Comment: I believe tagging ArcMap and arcpy together is incorrect and misleading, unless you're using it within ArcMap itself only. The majority of my arcpy use does not touch on any of these applications, rather are completely Independent. ArcGIS pro vs Arcgis-10.x would be the closest I could get in distinguishing the difference.

Comment: @Midavalo tagging [tag:arcpy] with [tag:arcgis-10.x] is certainly something that I had thought of and could support.  My only hesitancy is doing it while we are trying to get "non-version tag" consensus for ArcGIS Desktop.  To foreshadow my ArcGIS Desktop version tag thinking I would actually be happy to end up with [tag:arcgis-9.x], [tag:arcgis-10.0] and [tag:arcgis-10.1+] (not sure if "+" is allowed in a tag name) because since GIS SE was launched in 2010, the quantum leaps in ArcGIS Desktop from an arcgisscripting/ArcPy perspective came at 10.0 and 10.1 - the rest have been trivial.

Comment: understood. Perhaps the next tagging Q&A

Comment: @AndreSilva I'm happy to leave ArcPy out for this Q&A, and deal with how to tag it later, being cognizant that unlike the rest in the list it spans both ArcGIS Pro and ArcGIS Desktop 10.x architectures, so needs special attention.

Answer (score 3):

The main trigger (besides [Using tags [arcmap] and [arcgis-desktop]?](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4893)) for me considering this re-tagging is to accommodate the emergence of ArcGIS Pro, which is currently positioned by Esri as an application within the ArcGIS Desktop product.

Consequently, I think the re-tagging (mostly automatic with some manual) sequence needs to flow from that.  The steps here are not yet fully thought out so consider this answer to be a work in progress.

1. Manually review the [33 questions](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcgis-desktop+arcgis-pro) that are tagged with both `arcgis-desktop` and `arcgis-pro` to remove the `arcgis-desktop` tag from any that are only about ArcGIS Pro, and not about the ArcGIS Desktop 10.x applications (ArcMap, ArcCatalog, ArcGlobe and ArcScene)
2. Manually review the [27 questions](https://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Barcgis-desktop%5D%20%22arcgis%20pro%22%20-%5Barcgis-pro%5D+is%3Aquestion) that are tagged with `arcgis-desktop` and contain the string "ArcGIS Pro" (but are not tagged `arcgis-pro`) to see whether the `arcgis-desktop` tag should be removed and replaced by an `ArcGIS-pro` tag when they are only about ArcGIS Pro, and not about the ArcGIS Desktop 10.x applications (ArcMap, ArcCatalog, ArcGlobe and ArcScene)
3. Manually review the [142 questions](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcgis-desktop+arccatalog) that are tagged with both `arcgis-desktop` and `arccatalog` to remove the `arcgis-desktop` tag from any that are only about ArcCatalog
4. Manually review the [309 questions](https://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Barcgis-desktop%5D%20%22arccatalog%22%20-%5Barccatalog%5D%20is%3Aquestion) that are tagged with `arcgis-desktop` and contain the string "ArcCatalog" (but are not tagged `arccatalog`) to see whether the `arcgis-desktop` tag should be removed and replaced by an `arccatalog` tag when they are about ArcCatalog
5. Manually review the [12 questions](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcgis-desktop+arcglobe) that are tagged with both `arcgis-desktop` and `arcglobe` to remove the `arcgis-desktop` tag (and `3d-analyst` tag, when present) from any that are only about ArcGlobe
6. Manually review the [9 questions](https://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Barcgis-desktop%5D%20%22arcglobe%22%20-%5Barcglobe%5D%20is%3Aquestion) that are tagged with `arcgis-desktop` and contain the string "ArcGlobe" (but are not tagged `arcglobe`) to see whether the `arcgis-desktop` tag (and `3d-analyst` tag, when present) should be removed and replaced by an `arcglobe` tag when they are about ArcGlobe
7. Manually review the [127 questions](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcgis-desktop+arcscene) that are tagged with both `arcgis-desktop` and `arcscene` to remove the `arcgis-desktop` tag (and `3d-analyst` tag, when present) from any that are only about ArcScene
8. Manually review the [38 questions](https://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Barcgis-desktop%5D%20%22arcscene%22%20-%5Barcscene%5D%20is%3Aquestion) that are tagged with `arcgis-desktop` and contain the string "ArcScene" (but are not tagged `arcscene`) to see whether the `arcgis-desktop` tag (and `3d-analyst` tag, when present) should be removed and replaced by an `arcscene` tag when they are about ArcScene
9. Automatically merge any remaining [arcgis-desktop](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcgis-desktop) tags (this will be a large percentage of the current 17,121 questions) so that they are tagged with [arcmap](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcmap).

In step 9 I do not think that we should leave [arcgis-desktop](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcgis-desktop) behind as a synonym (we will eliminate it) and at that time it will have been burninated.  However, I think going the next step to blacklist it will be overkill.  If it re-emerges on any more than a smattering of occasions then blacklisting may be warranted.

I am sure that there may be some weaknesses with this approach but it will be best if we can identify them and adjust this plan before we commit to it.

Around the same time that a plan like this is committed to we can revise [Tagging ArcGIS questions?](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3131/tagging-arcgis-questions) to match its outcomes.

Comment: re: step #5, and the associated note about burninating the arcgis-desktop tag, have you put any consideration into whether there are any questions that are actually specific to ArcGIS Desktop as a whole?

Comment: @Midavalo Yes - but the only part of ArcGIS Desktop as a whole that spans its applications, besides ArcPy, ArcObjects and the ArcGIS Help (which we just tag as [tag:documentation]), that springs to mind is [tag:arcgis-license-manager].   I think that, like the extensions other than 3D, Network and Spatial, would overly complicate the discussion, if introduced at this stage.

Comment: +1. I suggest adding to the manual inspection/retagging, the following: example with [arcscene]; questions tagged [arcgis-desktop], not tagged [arcscene] but with the key word 'arcscene'. See [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Barcgis-desktop%5D+-%5Barcscene%5D+arcscene). It will be +79 for 'arcsecene', +722 for 'arccatalog', +30 for 'arcglobe' and +9 for 'arcpro'. I'll help reviewing, if suggestion is accepted. (/cc @Midavalo).

Comment: @AndreSilva I've updated the list of steps for "ArcGIS Pro" and "ArcPro" [sic], and agree on the others, will just take time I don't have at this instant to update the answer carefully to incorporate the others.